# Class hierarchy

Tags: php, scope

I have the follow code, which I expect to return "WORKED", But returning nothing.

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        echo('Foo::__construct()<br />');
    }

    public function start() {
        echo('Foo::start()<br />');

        $this->bar = new Bar();
        $this->anotherBar = new AnotherBar();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function test() {
        echo('Bar::test()<br />');

        return 'WORKED';
    }
}

class AnotherBar extends Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        echo('AnotherBar::__construct()<br />');

        echo($this->bar->test());
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->start();
```

**Router**:

```
Foo::__construct() <- From $foo = new Foo();
Foo::start() <- From Foo::__construct();
Foo::__construct() <- From $this->bar = new Bar();
AnotherBar::__construct() <- From $this->anotherBar = new AnotherBar();
```

Because I define `$bar` from `Foo` class, and, extend `AnotherBar` to `Foo`, I expect to get variables already defined from `Foo`.

I can't see what is wrong. Where cam I start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AnotherBar` instance never had its `start` method called so its `$this->bar` is undefined.

With errors being displayed you get the following messages:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined property: AnotherBar::$bar in - on line 20  
> Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object in - on line 20
> ```

You can include the following code right after you `<?php` line to see all errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Of course you can also do this via `php.ini` which would be a cleaner solution.